# Error when running code in Spreadsheet Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried running this script on google spreadsheet script editor but somehow, i am getting an error message everytime i runs it. Hence, your advice is much appreciated on this.

```
function import() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().clear();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B5').setValue('=IMPORTXML("http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=XBT&To=MYR","//div[@class='ucc-container']|//span[@class='uccResultAmount']"))
}
```

Comment: What kind of error are you seeing?

Comment: "Missing ) after argument list. (line 7, file "import")". 

That's the only thing stated but I am sure it has to do with the apostrophe (') used on ('ucc-container') and ('uccResultAmount') because it was able to run the script it when I changed them to the quotation mark (").

Comment: Have you tried using a different name for the function instead of `import`? I think `import` might be a reserved word.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I got your code to work. I escaped the single quotes in your formula.

```
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B5').setValue('=IMPORTXML("http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=XBT&To=MYR","//div[@class=\'ucc-container\']|//span[@class=\'uccResultAmount\']")')
```